# Failed implicit conversion in scala ensuring block

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I am using scalac 2.12.1 to compile the following program without any options:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

case class Int32(v : Int) {
}
case class Int64(v : BigInt) {
    def > (that : Int64) = this.v > that.v
    def <= (that : Int64) = this.v <= that.v
}
object implicits {
    implicit def int32Toint64(input : Int32) = Int64(BigInt(input.v))
}
import implicits._

class myTest {
    def max(x: Int64, y: Int32) : Int64 = {
        if (x > y)
            x
        else
            y  // If this is replaced with int32Toint64(y) it works !
    } ensuring(res => x <= res && y <= res) // <= error: missing parameter type for 'res'
}
```

The above program fails to compile with the error indicated in the comment. 
My expectation was that the implicit conversion `int32Toint64` will automatically take effect. Note that if I do the conversion explicitly, i.e., if I replace `y` with `int32Toint64(y)`, then the program compiles successfully. So I am puzzled. Why do I see this behavior ? Is there a way to prevent this error without the explicit conversion ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
class myTest {
    def max(x: Int64, y: Int32) : Int64 = {
        if (x > y)
            x
        else
            (y : Int64)
    } ensuring(res => x <= res && y <= res)
}
```

This also works:

```
class myTest {
    def max(x: Int64, y: Int32) : Int64 = ({
        if (x > y)
            x
        else
            y
    }: Int64) ensuring(res => x <= res && y <= res)
}
```

This obviously doesn't work:

```
class myTest {
    def max(x: Int64, y: Int32) : Int64 = {
        if (x > y)
            x
        else
            y
    } ensuring((res: Int64) => x <= res && y <= res)
}
```

Why? Look at this expression in isolation:

```
    {
        if (x > y)
            x
        else
            y
    }
```

What can a compiler possibly derive about it, if the type is not ascribed explicitly? It will derive something like `Serializable`, or even `AnyRef`. What else could it do? The typechecker works in a very straight forward fashion. It just looks at an expression, tries to derive the most precise type of it, and if no type is prescribed from the outside, it doesn't try to cast anything implicitly. And it does not start searching in remote corners of your code for additional type hints. In this case, `ensuring ( ... )` is neither part of this expression, nor does it allow the explicit return type ascription `: Int64 =` to trickle down.

I guess the best way to understand why this is obvious is to write a little typechecker for the simply typed lambda calculus: it is very simple, but it already exhibits exactly the same behavior in similar situations.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. I am new to Scala and what was confusing me was that the implicit conversion was not kicking-in even though the return type of the method is explicitly specified to be Int64. I can now see that the typechecker sees the code block in isolation from the method's return type.

Comment: That's exactly right: the "ensuring (...)" kind-of stands in the way between the block and the return type.